# Visual Studio 2015 - preview body of function on hovering

Tags: visual-studio-2015

In Eclipse, when one hover on name of a function/class, a floating window is opened and shows the body of the function/class. In VS, it shows only the prototype of this function/class. Is there a way to enable showing of whole body?

Comment: 'peek definition' from the context menu will be close.

Comment: I don't know if you can do it via hovering, but Ctr+click on a method name will open up the "peek definition" window

Comment: @Poorkenny the ctrl+click doesn't work for me. I see that in [Productivity Power Tools 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d) there is this option. Is there way to enable it without that installing?